# systemd service can't find dbt command

Tags: systemd

I have set up a systemd service to run prefect agent on Linux based this [article](https://discourse.prefect.io/t/how-to-run-a-prefect-2-agent-as-a-systemd-service-on-linux/1450), but it can't find the dbt command. Do anyone know how to let service catch dbt command?

I'm on GCP VM, Ubuntu, 20.04 LTS, amd64

Here is the service status:

```
prefect-agent.service - Prefect Agent
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/prefect-agent.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2023-03-28 02:03:07 UTC; 1min 53s ago
   Main PID: 140053 (prefect)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 19187)
     Memory: 139.6M
     CGroup: /system.slice/prefect-agent.service
             └─140053 /home/ulan/anaconda3/envs/zoomcamp/bin/python /home/ulan/an>

Mar 28 02:03:55 de-zoomcamp prefect[140053]:   File "/home/ulan/anaconda3/envs/zoomcamp/lib/python3.9/site-packages/prefect/engine.py", line 1438, in orchestrate_t_task_run
Mar 28 02:03:55 de-zoomcamp prefect[140053]:     result = await task.fn(*args, **kwargs)
Mar 28 02:03:55 de-zoomcamp prefect[140053]:   File "/home/ulan/anaconda3/envs/zoomcamp/lib/python3.9/site-packages/prefect_dbt/cli/commands.py", line 154, in trigger_dbt_cli_command
Mar 28 02:03:55 de-zoomcamp prefect[140053]:     result = await shell_run_command.fn(command=command, **shell_run_command_kwargs)
Mar 28 02:03:55 de-zoomcamp prefect[140053]:   File "/home/ulan/anaconda3/envs/zoomcamp/lib/python3.9/site-packages/prefect_shell/commands.py", line 114, in shell_run_command
Mar 28 02:03:55 de-zoomcamp prefect[140053]:     raise RuntimeError(msg)
Mar 28 02:03:55 de-zoomcamp prefect[140053]: RuntimeError: Command failed with exit code 127:
Mar 28 02:03:55 de-zoomcamp prefect[140053]: /tmp/prefect-655rr1g5: line 1: dbt: command not found
Mar 28 02:03:56 de-zoomcamp prefect[140053]: 02:03:56.020 | ERROR   | Flow run 'graceful-dolphin' - Finished in state Failed('Flow run encountered an exception. RuntimeError: Command failed with exit code 127:\n/tmp/prefect-655rr1g5: line 1: dbt: command not found\n\n')
Mar 28 02:03:56 de-zoomcamp prefect[140053]: 02:03:56.702 | INFO    | prefect.infrastructure.process - Process 'graceful-dolphin' exited cleanly.
```

My service code:

```
[Unit]
Description=Prefect Agent

[Service]
User=ulan
WorkingDirectory=/home/ulan/DE_zoomcamp_project/dbt/who_disease_data
ExecStart=/home/ulan/anaconda3/envs/zoomcamp/bin/prefect agent start -q "default"
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I have already installed the dbt-bigquery at local, and it works when I command prefect agent start -q "default" in terminal directly.

Comment: I see you're running `prefect` from `/home/ulan/anaconda3/envs/zoomcamp/bin`, so that's probably where you have the `dbt` command. Can you check if it's indeed in `/home/ulan/anaconda3/envs/zoomcamp/bin/dbt`?

Comment: It's indeed there. I have tried `ExecStartPre=/home/ulan/anaconda3/envs/zoomcamp/bin/dbt run`, and it works but I don't want to run dbt in systemd service. Is there any way can let systemd service know where dbt command is and not run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When any process tries to run a command that's specified without the full (or relative) path, it will look for the existence of the executable in every folder that exists in the `$PATH` environment variable. That's how you can run, for instance, `ls`, and not `/bin/ls` - because `/bin` exists in your `PATH` variable.

`dbt` is not in any of the standard paths - it's installed in `/home/ulan/anaconda3/envs/zoomcamp/bin`, so if this folder is not in the `PATH` environment variable of the service, the `prefect` agent wouldn't know where to find it.

Under the `[Service]` section in your file, add:

```
Environment="PATH=/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/home/ulan/anaconda3/envs/zoomcamp/bin"
```

Then when the agent looks for the `dbt` command, it will look in all the folders in the variable (in the specified order) and will finally find it at the last folder in the list, where the executable file is located.

Comment: Hi aviro, It's indeed because `$PATH` environment variable didn't have this directory. I added the dir to `$PATH` environment variable and it works! Thank you so much.